# My listview does not get any clicks anymore when I add a checkbox

Tags: java, android, listview

I created a listview with an image and some text with following layout and it worked. Whenever I clicked the Text "onListItemClick" was called successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="40dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I added a checkbox between the text and the image and I could no longer get the clicks when I click on the text and also not when I click the checkboxes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="40dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/check"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way so that I can get clicks on the checkboxes and the text ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the click event from the `ListView`, as in, do you want it to call "onListItemClick" when either the `CheckBox` or `TextView` is clicked? Or do you want to receive events on their own views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checkbox is probably stealing focus.

Try setting `android:focusable="false"` on the checkbox.

A side note:
Please note that there is a way to handle checkbox selects in lists where the framework takes care of most of the job. Set CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE on the list and use a layout that has for example a [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html). You can get ids using `getCheckedItemIds()`. See for example android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice . There are implementations in the api demos.
Don't try this on expandable list view though, since that won't handle the click ids correctly.

Comment: So any idea what to do with a ExpandableListView? I need to know which "item" i selected. What's the best solution for this if not by using check boxes?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the focusable attribute of the checkbox try setting it to android:focusable="false" in the layout